# Load only updated documents from firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am working on an app which uses cloud firestore as its database. I have a collection in the database which have multiple documents(like in hundreds or thousands). So when I load them for the first time at that time I am loading all the documents but from the next time, I only want to load that documents that have been changed or added recently.

**Note:**

1. I have tried adding snapshot listener on the whole collection but it is returning all the documents each and every time.
2. I have tried adding snapshot listener to the document. This is working. But I cannot add hundreds of listeners to the documents. As documents increase day by day.

Any other solution to this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Why are you fetching all of them? And can’t you structure your data in a different way? If you need to fetch all of the documents then there is probably a better way to structure your data to make a request for 1 (or a few) documents that contain the same data.

Comment: I am fetching all of them once to show the data on the graph, but after I have loaded the graph with the data then I only want to update the graph with the changes, not with the whole data again and again.

Comment: Then what you should be doing is storing the graph data in a separate document. Use a cloud function to keep the data updated. Store it in the format that you want to actually use it, but in a single document. Then when you want to load the graph you can just go straight to the "graph data" document and get your graph data.

Comment: But creating a new graph document and fetching all the data from this document will only lead to the less number of queries generated but not reduce the size of data received from firebase. As the graph document will contain all the data from the other documents. So the data size remains the same just the number of documents we have to read is reduced to 1. I am looking for a solution that also reduces the data size and also the cloud cost.

Comment: No, the graph data needs only enough data to display the graph. If you have to calculate a mean value or histogram values etc... then do that in a cloud function and then store it into your "graph data" document. Yes, you might have duplicate data but duplicate data is a lot less expensive than multiple reads.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I think though - you might consider additional Firestore structures to store your graph data and potentially a 'flag' of some kind to mark data as have been read. However, we don't know what kind of data you're dealing with or how it's being handled - adding a sample of your Firestore structure and what data you are needed to graph to your question may lead to a good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I seem to have the same problem with graphs.

These are the steps I took since I also used firestore.

1. Keep the collection structures by keeping in mind about the graph that you need to be shown in the client side.(In your case if this can be improved now, then that's a good start)
2. Show only the latest data onto the graph. I don't what kind of graph that you are building, but still if that graph contains some kind of timestamp attached to it I will probably use the latest 5/10 data to be shown in the graph, since firebase charge you for how much of data you retrieve back. And I think in your case it will cost you heavily since you are retrieving hundreds of data at a particular time.
3. snapshot is applied on all the documents in the collection level, please have a look at my code

   ```
         firebase
           .firestore()
           .collection(`devices`)
           .where('object', '==', load)
           .orderBy('added_at', 'desc')
           .limit(1)
           .onSnapshot(query => {
             query.docChanges().forEach(change => {
               if (change.type === 'added') {
                 const data = change.doc.data();
               }
             });
           });
   ```

As you can see, I am adding a where condition that reduces the number of documents firebase need to check for a snapshot change.

I still don't know this is what you wanted, but I think I could give you a general idea how firebase is at the moment with the current design of yours is costing you a lot.

Comment: Thanks for your answer as this may somewhat help me in finding the proper solution for my problem.

Answer (score 3):

I might be late, hope it helps other people.

You can store a timestamp inside eah document. Each time you update the document, set current time to that field.

After that simply do (in Java, but the main is idea, not language):

```
long lastUpdate = sharedPreferences.getLong("last update", 0); // get last time you have closed your application
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(new Date(lastUpdate));

db.collection("cities")
    .whereGreaterThan("updated", timestamp) // find all documents that updated while you where absent
    .get()
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                    
                    // load updates
                }
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried adding snapshot listener on the whole collection but it is returning all the documents each and every time.

This is the default behaviour. In such cases of hundreds or thousands of documents, you need to use some limitations as explained in the official documentation regarding [order and limit data in Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data).

> I have tried adding snapshot listener to the document. This is working. But I cannot add hundreds of listeners to the documents. As documents increase day by day.

That's not how you deal with documents. In general, we use [pagination](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors) to load data in smaller chunks. In this way you reduce the amount of documents that you read and in the same time you reduce the costs.